# Check if a string is a template literal in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, syntax, template-literals

Is it possible to test if a string is a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)?

Something like:

```
const x = "foo"
const y = `${x}bar`  // "foobar"

isTemplateLiteral(x) // false
isTemplateLiteral(y) // true
```

Comment: No, it's not possible. The closest you might get is wrapping this code into a function, then parsing its source (available via toString()-ing it). Still, it smells heavily as XY problem.

Comment: It would be better to ask if a string _is formed from_ a template literal, as `x` and `y` will always be strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Template literal is only a syntax/javascript structure, and not a new type of object in the language.
The value of the template literal is generated when the processor goes over the line of code and the returned value is a string, hence - you can't check if the value was generated by string literal or by a regular string.

Btw, if you use babel and you want the output to be valid ES5 - the string literals will be converted to some sort of string concatenate (var y = `x + 'bar'`).